# Visual issue when printing edge weights in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I am trying to place edge weight in a network that I draw in `tikz`, however, it does not show up as I wanted.

[image]

I am providing a MWE below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35,auto=left,minimum size=2mm ,every node/.style={circle,fill=black}, text=white, minimum size=0.3 cm,  font = \scriptsize]
     \node (v1) at (5,6) {C};
     \node (v2) at (-1,6) {B};
     \draw  (v1) edge node{1} (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why does the edge weight show up like a node? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it *is* a node, and you've set `every node/.style={...}` in the options to the `tikzpicture` ...

One workaround is to use a `scope` environment and set `every node` for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=.35,
  auto=left,
%  minimum size=0.3 cm,
  font = \scriptsize
  ]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,fill=black, text=white,}]
     \node (v1) at (5,6) {C};
     \node (v2) at (-1,6) {B};
\end{scope}
     \draw  (v1) edge node{1} (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```